# How can I unit test my facebook login using passport js in mocha nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, passport.js, zombie.js

I am new to unit testing. I have been writing test case using mocha for Nodejs. In my case need to write test case for facebook login. I have firstly tried with facebook-mock but i was not able to complete the task.This is my test case where I have used **zombie**,

```
var chai = require('chai');    
var assert = chai.assert;    
var server;    
var Browser = require('zombie');    
describe("login using social sites",function () {
  this.timeout(40000);
  beforeEach(function () {
    server = require('../../../server').server;
    browser = new Browser({ site: 'http://localhost:3000' });
  });
        it("should login with facebook",function (done) {

        browser.visit('/auth/facebook',function (err,brw) {

            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            assert.equal(brw.location.pathname, '/auth/facebook/callback');

            done();

        });



    });


    afterEach(function () {
        server.close();
    });

});
```

And the **server.js** file is,

```
var express = require('./config/express');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Server running at %s', port);
});

module.exports = {
    app : app,
    server : server
};
```

This is the error which i have got after executing the unit test,

```
 1) login using social sites should login with facebook:
     Uncaught TypeError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
      at G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\lib\pipeline.js:89:15
      at tryCatcher (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:504:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:561:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:606:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:681:18)
      at Async._drainQueue (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:16)
      at Async._drainQueues (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:148:10)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (G:\Janani\Tasks\CCSProject\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
```

Please anyone guide me to fix this issue. And if any other specific framework if available please guide me with that. **Thanks in Advance!!**

Comment: `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000` clearly shows that no application is running on specified port 3000.Please check whether some application is running on port 3000.

Comment: `var express = require('./config/express');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Server running at %s', port);
});

module.exports = {
    app : app,
    server : server
};`   This is my **server.js** file which i have initialized in before each hook of my test case. Other test case is running with this port only for this i face the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got fixed with this issue!!!

```
describe("login using social sites",function () {

    this.timeout(40000);


    beforeEach(function () {
        server = require('../../../server').server;

        // browser = new Browser({ site: 'http://localhost:3000' });



    });


    it("should login with facebook",function (done) {

        Browser.visit('http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/facebook',function (err,brw) {

            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            brw.fill('email','aaa@gmail.com').fill('pass', 'password')
                .pressButton('login', function (err,brow) {
                    brw.assert.success();
                    done();
                });

        });



    });


    afterEach(function () {
        server.close();
    });

});
```